# Hamiltonian Cycle and Bipartite Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Explain why $K_{2,3}$ cannot have a Hamilton cycle.

I can visibly see and show why this is the case, but is there a mathematical proof or specific way of explaining how this Hamilton cycle cannot exist? Thanks a ton for all the help!

Comment: Which book are u using if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 2):

The graph $K_{2,3}$ is bipartite, and a bipartite graph cannot contain an odd cycle. Since $|V(K_{2,3})| = 5$, this graph can not contain a hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: Okay, that was what I was thinking. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution, and possibly the reason why you can visibly see that there is no Hamiltonian cycle, is as follows:

Let $S$ be the larger part of this bipartite graph. Then $|S| = 3$, $|N(S)| = 2$, and $S$ is an independent set. Whenever there is a set of vertices $S$ of a graph with $S$ an independent set and $|N(S)| > |S|$, then the graph cannot contain a Hamiltonian cycle. (To prove this, use contradiction to assume that there is a Hamiltonian cycle, then get that $|N(S)| \geq |S|$.)